# How To Add User To Cell Showing Who Edited Row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script for GOogle Sheets that works almost perfectly.I just need one addition:
To add the logged in user to the cell.
I have a sheet called "GMB Descriptions"
When a user enters information in any cell row in column 4, it shows the date & time in column 5 of the same row. No problem.
The issue is I want it to show the logged in user in that cell as well
Currently (script below) shows: **MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm a**
I want it to show: **MM/dd/yyyy - hh:mm a - LoggedIn User**
I understand it would use the user email who made the change to that row.

Summary: How do I add the code to the following script to also show the user who made that edit?

```html
function onEdit() {
 var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if( s.getName() == "GMB Descriptions" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
   if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
     var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
       var time = new Date();
       time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-8", "MM/dd/yy - h:mm a");
       nextCell.setValue(time);
   };
 };
}
```

Comment: You should "ask" active user to run the auth script manually (by button click, for example). This script will take Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() value indeed. You can use this value in onEdit script then. onEdit has limited auth mode and can not take email directly.

Comment: Hello,, I don't want to "ask" the user to do anything. I just want the users account (email) to show in the cell. That's all.

This script does it: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73476/how-to-show-last-edited-date-and-user-on-google-sheets

but only in one cell. I want to add it to my original so it does it for each row every time a change is made to the row. So question is how do I add it to the original script?

Comment: Thank you for the link. You see, here `e.user.getEmail()` is used. The problem is that it has limited functionality (security reason). For example it will NOT work if the Sheet is shared by hyperlink for editing.

Comment: This sheet is only shared internally and only for people who are logged in - so the security issue, is not an issue.

Comment: https://www.useloom.com/share/06337fb1e3764cdabc1edd8adc4df6ec

Comment: You should not run onEdit(e) manually. It is triggered by the cell editing... Have you read about [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var rg=e.range;
 var sh=rg.getSheet();
 var name=sh.getName();
 if( name=="GMB Descriptions") { 
   if( rg.columnStart==4) { 
     var nextCell = rg.offset(0, 1);
     if( nextCell.getValue()=='') { 
       var dt=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy - h:mm a");
       nextCell.setValue(Utilities.formatString('%s\n%s',dt,Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())
- [Restrictions with Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)
- [Restrictions with Installable Triggeres](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it didn't work. I am getting "ReferenceError: "e" is not defined. (line 2, file "Code")Dismiss"

It so happens the number of columns in the sheet is 13, and it is supposed to check for changes in column 14 (if that helps)...

Comment: Oh it looks like I forgot to put the e parameter in the function.

Comment: How are you testing it? It works for me.  When I enter something in column4 and there's nothing in column5 it puts the date and time and my email in column5.  If you want to use this with other to get other users emails your going to have to use an installable trigger.  Read the [restrictions on simple triggers.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

The modified (and slightly reduced) script is below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getSheet().getName() == "GMB Descriptions" && rg.columnStart == 4) { 
    var nextCell = rg.offset(0, 1);
    if (nextCell.getValue() == '') {
      var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy - h:mm a - ");
      var userMail = e.user.getEmail();
      nextCell.setValue(dt + userMail);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to Cooper for **Utilities** hint, it works fine. We use `e.user.getEmail()` assuming no security problems (according to asker opinion). While testing for me, it works as expected.